# Tag Synonyms - Is our community using them effectively?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I feel as if our community could make a better usage of the tag synonym feature of the StackExchange.

If you are unaware of the feature - [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work)

We have tags like:

- [api-23](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api-23) > [winter-12](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winter-12)
- [api-26](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api-26) > [winter13](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winter13)
- [api-27](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api-27) > [spring-13](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spring-13)

These tags fall under the category of **exact duplicates**. However, there are other examples of child tag synonyms or subset tags that we could utilize:

- [ide](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ide) > [eclipse](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eclipse)
- [api](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) > [metadata-api](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metadata-api)

I'm not sure if the restrictions are too strict and make it difficult for the community to manage our tags, but looking at our tag list I believe we could do a better job cleaning them up and providing better descriptions for tags to make the system easier to use.

A proper tagging system makes it simpler for users to find information (and search engines) and it allows for other users to just follow tags they are interested in and not have to worry about keeping up with the site as much.

Let's all try to make an effort to clean it up a bit when you get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

Great point, Jesse.  I think it can help to create solid tag descriptions and tag wikis and to   fix obviously incorrectly tagged questions.

Sometimes, it might not be as clear.  I think that the [api](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) tag actually is supposed to refer to a higher-level, generic concept of an API, and not necessarily the specific metadata-api, so a question about the metadata API could actually be tagged with both.  Someone might be following APIs in general or the metadata API, specifically.

Comment: There is more discussion about the api tags here: http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4/api-tags-soap-rest-etc-or-soap-api-rest-api-etc